# How do I call a method from my outer class in an inner class of my custom-made linked list?

Tags: python, linked-list, inner-classes

I'm learning python and challenging myself by writing my own linked list from scratch. I'm using a tradition structure of an inner node class which holds a piece of data and a reference to the next node. Right now I'm trying to create a `__repr__` method that returns a string representation of a node. The string it returns looks like this: `"This node contains {0}. The next node is {1}." .format(self.data, self.next.data)`

It works fine unless there's only 1 node in the list, which gave me the following error: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'data'.`

To get around this, I check first to see if there's only one node in the list, and I return the following string: `"This node contains {0}. There is no next node." .format(self.data)`

This is what my `__repr__` method looks like right now:

```
      def __repr__(self):
            if MyLinkedList.get_size() == 1:
                return "This node contains {0}. There is no next node." . format(self.data)
            return "This node contains {0}. The next node is {1}." .format(self.data, self.next.data)
```

This is what the whole linked list class looks like so far:

```
class MyLinkedList(object):

    head = None
    size = None

    def __init__(self):
        self.size = 0

    def get_head(self):
        return self.head

    def get_size(self):
        return self.size

    def is_empty(self):
        if self.size == 0:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def __repr__(self):
        result = "["
        curr = self.head
        while curr != None:
            if curr.next == None:
                result += curr.data
                break
            result += curr.data
            result += ", "
            curr = curr.next
        result += "]"
        return result

    def add_to_head(self, data):
        new_node = MyLinkedList.Node(data)
        if self.size == 0:
            self.head = new_node
        else:
            new_node.next = self.head
            self.head = new_node
        self.size += 1

    def delete_from_head(self):
        if (self.size == 0):
            self.head = None
        else:
            new_head = self.head.next
            self.head = new_head
        self.size =- 1

    class Node():

        next = None

        def __init__(self, data):
            self.data = data

        def get_data(self):
            return self.data

        def get_next(self):
            return self.next

        def __repr__(self):
            if MyLinkedList.get_size() == 1:
                return "This node contains {0}. There is no next node." . format(self.data)
            return "This node contains {0}. The next node is {1}." .format(self.data, self.next.data)
```

But now when I try to print the string representation of any node, it gives me the following error: `TypeError: get_size() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'`

Is there any way to fix this issue? All I'm trying to do is to call my outer class's get_size() method in my inner node class, and check if that value is 1. Is there any other way to make it so my node's `__repr__` method returns the string I want it to return when there's only one node in the list?

Also, if you spot other improvements you could make to my code, I would be glad to hear them.

Comment: Don't try to call the linked list's `get_size` method from the node's `__repr__` method. A node only knows about the value it contains, and its `next` reference. You can check to see if `next` is `None`. If it is, there is no next node.

Comment: Please provide a [mre], which in the case means add code that creates a linked list and tries to print a string representation of a node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only invoke `get_size()` on an instance of your `MyLinkedList` class. A node shouldn't know anything about the linked list class anyway. Just take advantage of the node's `next` pointer instead:

```
def __repr__(self):
    suffix = "There is not next node" if self.next is None else "The next node is {}".format(self.next.data)
    return "This node contains {}. {}.".format(self.data, suffix)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to add a self argument into the get_size() method. Such as:

```
def __repr__(self):
            if MyLinkedList.get_size(self) == 1:
                return "This node contains {0}. There is no next node." . format(self.data)
            return "This node contains {0}. The next node is {1}." .format(self.data, self.next.data)
```